# "Run Recipe" menu option of MVC4 is missing from Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, recipe

The "Run Recipe" menu option of MVC4 is missing from Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Is anyone else facing a similar problem, or it is just me?

Thanks
Mk

Comment: I'm going to guess this question has been solved already or does not matter anymore.